# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and Nvidia dirver (304.51) 64bit: problem 640x480

Tags: nvidia

I have a problem with this configuration:

Asus K55V, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Nvidia driver 304.51.

I have remove the nouveau driver with:

```
apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

I installed the official nvidia driver (from www.nvidia.com) but when I reboot the PC the resolution of screen is only 640x480 and the monitor is resized.

Mo solution at this problem if i change the `xorg.conf`.

Now i have uninstall the nvidia driver and reinstall with

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

When I reboot the screen resolution and size is OK, but if I start `nvidia-setting` I received the message:

> You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.

and with command:

```
sudo lshw -c display | grep driver
```

I received

> configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

This sound like the system is using the Intel card. When I launch command `lspci | grep 
VGA` the output is:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1058 (rev ff)

And there is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I have read a lot of guides on internet but without success.. How i can use nvidia card with the driver that i have installed?

Comment: if i add a resolution other than 640 to the device "monitor" the result is the same..

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same problem with my Asus A55V, which is just got a few days ago and I'm getting it all set up with Ubuntu 12.10.  If you look in windows, you will find that the nvidia card is not the primary card that actually connects to the LCD.  In windows, programs that are made to use graphics acceleration will use the nvidia GPU and memory if configured correctly.  This method of working is a hybrid situation (see http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html ) I think the idea is to save power on the laptop by only using the GPU when necessary. 
I've found this project which aims to provide the ability to use 3D acceleration in linux: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee It has all the instructions on there to set it up in Ubuntu. 
Hopefully that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

[After nvidia driver update screen is 640x480. How to undo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216105/after-nvidia-driver-update-screen-is-640x480-how-to-undo)

In particular, the solution given in the top comment on the question usually works for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all 
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Nvidia Optimus and you will need to have Bumblebee to make it work properly.

Its the Intel graphic card that'll be used for normal use and the Nvidia when you need more power. The Intel card can handle normal use of the computer.

Read more about Bumblebee and how to install it here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

After install you need to run

`optirun program` to use your Nvidia card, everything else use the Intel card.

You must remove the installed Nvidia drivers before installing Bumblebee because Bumblebee install whats needed.

It works great for me, hopes it do it for you too.